# What's the minimum number of people required?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Now there is a $n\times n$ square matrix, and then take $m$ rows and $m$ columns randomly. At least one intersection stood a man. How many people need to stand in this square matrix at least?

The original problem is an interesting puzzle, I'll express it in the form of a story.

> A Clever King and a Condemned Man
> Once upon a time,a famous condemned man is about to be executed.But the
> clever King didn't want him to die hastily. So before the execution, the king pointed to the formation in front of him and said:
> 'Now there is a formation which has 7 rows and 7 columns,You choose 33 soldiers and let them leave the formation,The remaining soldiers stand still, and then I choose 3 rows and 3 columns.If at least one soldier stands at the 9 intersections, you will be free,otherwise, the excution will continue.'
> So how should the condemned man arrange the soliders to ensure that he will not be executed?

When I saw this puzzle, I guessed that the solution must follow some symmetry, so there must be 2 soldiers in each row and column, but I found that no matter how I arranged, at least 17 soldiers were required. Then I simulated a solution with computer (as shown in the figure below),then I found that the solution of only using 16 soliders exists and the solution was asymmetric, so my idea was wrong.

One of the solutions:
$\begin{array}{1}
1&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&1&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1
\end{array}
$

According to the answer,I have been conscious that this question is equivalent to **Zarankiewicz problem**. Except for few cases, no satisfactory solution to the problem is known.And if we know the value of Z(n,n,m,m),we will get the answer to my problem:
$n^2-Z(n,n,m,m)+1$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Think of the worst case scenario... those $m$ rows and $m$ columns you picked happen to have every intersection without a person there and all other positions in the matrix did have a person there...  (*why are we talking in terms of "persons" here rather than 1's and 0's?*).  Add one to that and conclude.  $n^2-m^2+1$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Did you get this problem from anywhere?

Comment: This problem comes from a chat group,sadly,I don't know what the answer is.

Comment: @JMoravitz it's not that simple now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the story's specific puzzle ($n=7,m=3$) is in fact both optimal and unique up to permutations of rows and columns; here's its "nicest" presentation:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
&&1&1&&&\\
&1&&&1&&\\
1&&&&&1&\\
1&&&1&1&&\\
&1&&1&&1&\\
&&1&&1&1&\\
&&&&&&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

The general problem is extremely hard (Zarankiewicz's problem). For example, let $a_n$ be the solution for an $n×n$ board with $m=3$, then the $a_n$ follow no discernible pattern (and hence have been included in the OEIS as [A350237](https://oeis.org/A350237)):
$$\{a_n\}_{n\ge1}=(0,0,1,3,5,10,16,22,32,40,52,64,77,91,105,128\dots)$$
For more information see my arXiv paper "[An attack on Zarankiewicz's problem through SAT solving](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.02283)".

Comment: +1 That sequence isn't in OEIS. Consider adding it.

Comment: @EthanBolker I found out that this is essentially the Zarankiewicz problem [A001198](https://oeis.org/A001198).

Comment: @EthanBolker My specific sequence will go onto the OEIS anyway as [A350237](https://oeis.org/A350237) – I've found the next term in A001198 without knowing it.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I'm truly grateful for your help!